# How to change or call svg clippath polygon attributes in CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, maps

Recently I exported a map document from the ESRI ArcMap 10.2.2 to SVG.

I would like to animate this map with css and javascript however the "clippath" polygons that arcmap creates makes it impossible to do so. How would can I get the group "Puerto Rico" to highlight over mouseover.

This is a summary of the code:

```
<svg width="1008pt" height="612pt" viewBox="0 0 1008 612" enable-background="new 0 0 1008 612"  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="Puerto_Rico_and_Virgin_Islands">
<g id="state" class="test">
    <g id="Puerto_Rico">
        <clipPath id="SVG_CP_1">
            <path d= coordinates are put in here />
        </clipPath>
    </g>
</g>
```

The CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
.test{
fill: grey;
stroke:#fff;
stroke-width:0.75;
stroke-opacity:1;
fill: orange;
}
#state:hover {
fill: red !important;
</style>
```

The real code:

visit jsfiddle for the entire code http://jsfiddle.net/jwitcoski/arv4g21f/3/

Using the wikipedia svg map that does not use clippath I was able to get everything to work. http://jsfiddle.net/jwitcoski/y3yhgjjy/9/

Comment: Your SVG sample won't display anything as is.  It is missing what the clipPath is designed to clip.  It is hard to tell what a solution might be without that.

Comment: Thank you for looking at it.  visit jsfiddle for the entire code at http://jsfiddle.net/jwitcoski/arv4g21f/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clipPath issue is a red herring.  It has nothing to do with why your CSS isn't working.

The reason your sample fiddle wasn't working was for two reasons:

1. Your CSS was missing a closing '}'.  But I am guessing this was just a typo introduced in your fiddle.
2. The main reason was that your path definition for PR had a presentation attribute for `fill`.

   `<path fill="none" ... />`

   This presentation attribute has a higher priority than the CSS rule because it is more specific and thus over-rides it.  If you remove the `fill="none"`, everything works.

[Demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/arv4g21f/4/)

Comment: I mis-spoke a little on my explanation.  I have corrected it.